# Is there an explanation why She-Hulk’s voice doesn’t change when she transforms?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, the-incredible-hulk, she-hulk

In She-Hulk show I noticed that Jennifer Walters's voice doesn't change after she becomes She-Hulk, which is not the case with Hulk, where his voice is different from Bruce Banner's.

Did they explain why is that the case?

Comment: ??? Smart Hulk's voice is Bruce Banner's (Ruffalo's) unaltered voice. There's no difference any more. Jennifer never went through the earlier stages of Hulking; she's already got "the brains with the brawn." But I don't know if this voice point was explained on the show.

Comment: I like your comment. Please put as an answer and I will accept. Maybe add that Hulk's different voice came with different Hulk personality that Bruce Banner doesn't control, where in his current smart Hulk's version, he is in control and voice is matched, similar to what is happening with She-Hulk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, her voice did change.

In the first episode, where you see her origin, her voice is noticeably different when she first becomes She-Hulk after the crash.  Later in the episode when she is confronted by some men in the parking lot of the bar and changes to She-Hulk you once again hear the different voice.

Once she has learned to control her She-Hulk abilities, that is when you first see that her voice is the same.  Although it is not explicitly explained, the implication is that once an individual has control over their Hulk abilities, they also have control over their voice to be able to sound like their normal self.

Comment: I rewatched the first episode and her scream is a "hulky scream" but talking voice is never been "hulky" voice. I would still accept your answer as Bruce was surprised when she talked first time and asked her if there is another voice and she said not.